# JavaScript: Using Async/Await in a Promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

On the way of learning the concepts of asynchronous JavaScript, I got struggled with the idea behind the situation when they can be chained. As an example consider the following situation: a webhook calls a cloud function and as a requirement there is set a *time interval* by which the cloud function should response to the webhook. In the cloud function is called an operation for fetching some data from a database, which can be short- or long-running task. For this reason we may want to return a promise to the webhook just to "register" a future activity and later provide results from it e.g.:

```
async function main () {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            db.getSomeData().then(data=> {
               resolve({ result: data});
            });
        } catch (err) {
            reject({ error: err.message });
        }
    });
}
```

Another way is to use `async`/`await` instead of a promise for fetching the data, e.g.:

```
async function main () {
    return new Promise (async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const data = await db.getSomeData();
            resolve({ result: data });
        } catch (err) {
            reject({ error: err.message });
        }
    });
}
```

(The code is a pseudo-code and therefore all checks on the returned types are not considered as important.)

Does the `await` block the code in the second example and prevent returning of the promise?

Comment: Why would you use new Promise inside an async function to wrap something that _already returns a promise_?

Comment: When you declare a function `async`, it automatically returns a promise. The point if this is that you can write more natural code, without having to nest promises like this.

Comment: Got it. And if case that there is no `async` at the main function?

Comment: Then you return a promise.

Comment: Whether you use `await` or `.then()` internally to the function is a style decision, they're pretty much equivalent.

Comment: Alright. I misunderstood it with the fact that `await` blocks until the action gets completed, whether `.then()` does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`async` functions always return a `Promise`. It is up to the function caller to determine how to handle it: either by chaining with `then/catch` or using `await`. In your example, there is no need to create and return a new `Promise`.

You could do something like this for example:

```js
async function main () {
  try {
    const data = await db.getSomeData()
    return {result: data}
  } catch (err) {
    return {error: err.message}
  }
}

// On some other part of the code, you could handle this function
// in one of the following ways:
//
// 1. 
// Chaining the Promise with `then/catch`.
main()
  .then((result) => console.log(result)) // {result: data}
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))      // {error: err.message}
// 2. 
// Using await (provided we are working inside an asyn function)
try {
  const result = await main()
  console.log(result) // {result: data}
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err)    // {error: err.message}
}
```

Try to avoid combining both methods of handling asynchronous operations as a best practice.